# Android - How do I get package details for dynamic intents

Tags: android, android-intent

So I am making a custom app chooser. It will have the browsers installed, and any map applications installed. I get each of these as follows:

```
PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();      
//This gets all the browsers
String browserURI = "http://"+Driver.getIamhereURL()+lat+","+lon;
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(browserURI));

List<ResolveInfo> browserList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(browserIntent, 0);

// This gets all the Map apps:
String mapUri = "geo:"+lat+","+lon;
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mapUri));

List<ResolveInfo> mapList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mapIntent, 0);

//Combine the two
browserList.addAll(mapList);
//Now build layout and return a LinearLayout
LinearLayout appListBody = buildAppList(browserList,packageManager);
```

So `appListBody` will containt the app icon and app name hopefully. Obviously each app will have to have an `onClickListener()` associated with it, which will launch the `intent`. My problem is, how do I send the `intent` to my method, when all I can get is `List<ResolveInfo> listOfApps`?

I can try a `for` loop and go `pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(listOfApps.get(count).resolvePackageName)` but then I get `NullPointerException: package name is null`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is, how do I send the intent to my method, when all I can get is List listOfApps?

You can construct a suitable `Intent` yourself:

```
  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,
                                 int position, long id) {
    ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                         activity.name);
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);

    startActivity(i);     
  }
```

This is from my [Launchalot](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) sample project, which has a `ListView` on an adapter full of `ResolveInfo` objects.

I would think that your solution would be equivalent if not superior, but you will need to use `activity.applicationInfo.packageName` to get the package to use. `resolvePackageName` is not what you think it is. :-)

Comment: Ah I see! I was using `resolvePackageName`. On that note, am I using the correct method of getting the icon? Because none is showing up. I also tried `appImage.setImageResource(listOfApps.get(count).activityInfo.icon);` but there's still no icon showing up.

Comment: Cool. I managed to get it by using `appImage.setImageDrawable(pm.getApplicationIcon(listOfApps.get(count).activityInfo.packageName));`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ResolveInfo` if you want to get package name try this:

```
(ResolveInfo Object).activityInfo.packagename;
```

This will return a string of package Name.

Comment: that helped me! since resolveInfo.resolvePackageName returned null all the time!